# Hosting a Git repository on an AWS Windows Server

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to host my own private Git setup on an AWS Windows Server instance.

Here is my setup:

- OpenSSH installed via cygwin

  - This works.  I have successfully SSHed into my server
- Git Daemon installed via cygwin

  - This seems to work.  I have successfully created and cloned repos locally using the Git bash
- Outgoing Firewall rule allowing TCP on ports 22 and 9418
- Incoming Firewall rule allowing TCP on ports 22 and 9418

  - I'm not sure this is required.

As far as I can tell, this is all I need, except that I can't clone the repo.

I'm using this command remotely:

`git clone ssh://myUser@myServer.com/git/myRepo`

And I get this output:

```
Clone into 'myRepo'
fatal: Could not read from the remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

However, the exact same command works fine when I run it on `myServer`'s through Git bash... which leads me to believe this is a firewall issue.  I can't seem to find which port is needed, though.

Extra details:

- My repo was initialized using `git init --bare --shared`
- My AWS Instance's security group (SG) has the following rules (currently for debugging)

  - Inbound

    - Port, Source: `ALL    0.0.0.0/0`
  - Outbound

    - Port, Source: `ALL    0.0.0.0/0`

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Could [this](http://gitweb.codeplex.com/) or [this](http://bonobogitserver.codeplex.com/) help? These tools allow to serve Git using IIS (via `HTTP[S]` protocol, obviously).

Comment: @kostix Those are great options, thanks!  If I can't get this current setup working I'll switch to one of these recommendations.  Thanks.

Comment: Port 9418 is only used for the git:// protocol, so not necessary if you're using ssh

Comment: @MetaFight, how did it go? Did you try out any of the Git over IIS options? I'm tempted to do the same... :D

Comment: I ended up using deveo.com for the time being.  I will eventually return to setting up my own Git repo, but I may just spin up a Linux instance on Amazon instead of using Windows Server.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the 'myUser' user has access to `/git/myRepo`? Note that that's root-relative, not relative to myUser's home dir.

If you want the path to be relative to the user's home dir, try a clone url of the format `myUser@myServer.com:git/myRepo`.

Also make sure that a bare repo's been created in `/git/myRepo` - i.e. if you `ls /git/myRepo`, you see `HEAD`, `hooks`, `refs`, `config`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ports 9418 and 22 are open in your SG, not just your windows firewall.

Keep in mind that the default SG is setup to deny *all* traffic, so ensure that you select `SSH` from `Create A New Rule` and ensure that the CIDR specified matches your CIDR, or alternatively `0.0.0.0/0` for everyone.

For your `git` protocol port, create a `custom rule` with 9418 as the port and the source as specified in your SSH selection.

If that doesn't resolve the issue double or triple check your security group (make sure you hit apply rule!), if possible post your rules. There is a good chance something in the SG is causing the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  I've posted more information in my question.  I don't think it's SG related, as I currently allow all incoming and outgoing traffic.  This will be locked down once I figure out what I'm doing ;)

Comment: No worries, I was going to suggest the same :), is your Windows firewall configured to allow port 22 and 9418?

Comment: Indeed it is.  I may simply ditch this approach for the HTTP alternative.

Comment: @MetaFight, first try connecting using SSH client instead of making Git run it for you. This depends on what you're using as your Git client. If this is on a POSIX system, just run `ssh myUser@myServer.com`, if this is Git for Windows, then either run the same command from the "Git shell" (`bash`) prompt (if you're using bundled OpenSSH client -- you are, if you do not know) or `plink myUser@myServer.com` if you're using PuTTY. Try to supply the client one or more `-v` command-line options to increase verbosity.

Comment: If you're going that route, why not check out Bitbucket.org? Free private repo's with git and Mercural and you eliminate the administration overhead of the server ( if the repo is it's sole use )

Comment: @MetaFight, if the `SSH` client logs you in correctly, the problem is with Git, so try to run `git --version` once logged in to check if it's runnable. If you cannot log, check your Git-side `SSH` setup.

Comment: To add to Kostix's comment: You may also want to check if the ports are open on the server as well using `netstat -an` if the port is not listening than there is your issue

Comment: ...and in fact there are [lots of Git hosting providers](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitHosting), not just bitbucket, and most of them offer private hosting. This is not suitable for security-sensitive data though (including that representing trade secrets etc).